# Renaming files on Amazon S3 through Craft backend

Tags: assets, s3

I've read somewhere you can't rename files on Amazon S3, which might explain my not being able to rename assets hosted on S3? Or, have P&T found a way around this and I've just not set the right user permissions?

My current permissions for this user are:

```
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:DeleteObject"
        ],
```

Thanks,
Clive

Comment: I believe you can change file names on S3. There is a rename option in the actions dropdown. Are you trying to change the file name in your control panel assets tab?

Comment: Through the Craft backend. Looking at the object policies, I think this might be not be possible: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/SOAPObjectsOps.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely possible in Craft PRO -- I just tested with fine results (latest ver. 2.4.2670). So I would look at your IAM policy. If you have your policy statement scoped to the one bucket in question (and not to all buckets in your account), you could use some wildcard permissions for your main actions, like this, and I think you should be able to rename:

```
"Action": [
    "s3:Delete*",
    "s3:Get*",
    "s3:List*",
    "s3:Put*"
],
```

There is no "Update" call into S3 since it is object storage, and any change means a full rewrite of the file.